# How to check all the columns of a dataframe are the same?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is a quick way to check if all the columns in a pandas dataframe are the same?

E.g. I have a dataframe with the columns a,b,c below, and I need to check that the columns are all the same, i.e. that a = b = c

```
+---+---+---+
| a | b | c |
+---+---+---+
| 5 | 5 | 5 |
| 7 | 7 | 7 |
| 9 | 9 | 9 |
+---+---+---+
```

I had thought of using apply to iterate over all the rows, but I am afraid it might be inefficient as it would be a non-vectorised loop.

I suspect looping over the columns would be quicker because I always have fewer columns than rows (a few dozen columns but hundreds of thousands of rows).

I have come up with the contraption below. I need to tidy it up and make it into a function but **it works - the question is if there is a more elegant / faster way of doing it?**

`np.where` returns zero when the items are all the same and 1 otherwise (not the opposite), so summing the output gives me the number of mismatches.

I iterate over all the columns (excluding the first), comparing them to the first.

The first output counts the matches/mismatches by column, the second by row.
If you add something like

```
df.iloc[3,2] = 100
```

after defining `df`, the output tells you the 3rd row of column c doesn't match

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame()
x = np.arange(0,20)
df['a'] = x
df['b'] = x
df['c'] = x
df['d'] = x

#df.iloc[3,2] = 100

cols = df.columns
out = pd.DataFrame()

for c in np.arange(1, len(cols) ):
    out[cols[c]] = np.where(df[cols[0]] == df[cols[c]], 0, 1)
    
print(out.sum(axis = 0))

print(out.sum(axis = 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `duplicated`:

```
(~df.T.duplicated()).sum()==1
# True
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`df.drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) and check for the `len` to be `1`. This would mean that all columns are same:

```
In [1254]: len(df.T.drop_duplicates()) == 1
Out[1254]: True
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`DataFrame.duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) + [`DataFrame.all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df.T.duplicated(keep=False).all()
#True
```